# closed-form solution for 1/tanh(x) - 1/x that can be evaluated at/near x=0?

Tags: numerical-methods, hyperbolic-functions

I'm looking to evaluate $\frac{1}{\tanh x}-\frac{1}{x}$ over a range that includes x=0. Is there an alternate form that is both exact, and numerically stable at/near x=0? For now I'm using the Taylor series $x/3-x^3/45+(2 x^5)/945$ for $|x|<0.01$ but it seems hacky to do so.

[image: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/img?i=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427edv2ojqjdl0&f=HBQTQYZYGY4TQM3EMI3WENBWGUYDCM3GGVSDKZRZGFRTGMBWMMYQaaaa]

I'm hoping this is similar to the case of the [quadratic formula](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/articles/Quadratics.pdf), which has alternate forms $x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and $x=\frac{2c}{-b \mp \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}$ that can be used for accurate solutions when $|4ac| \ll b^2$.

Comment: Seems quite a good approximation to me. Your function is real analytic, meaning it equals its power series. Furthermore, one may use Taylor's theorem with remainder to give explicit bounds on the error, once having chosen a finite length part of the Taylor series. 
Meanwhile, I left a different sort of answer on your 2010 question about orthogonal matrices with all entries in the first row the same.

Comment: Did you try Galerkin approximation over the domain? What are the limits of the domain? and are we allowed to use boundary values?